# Revert or execute function in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, undefined, draggable, revert

I'm looking to revert the element to it's original position if it hasn't been dragged by more than a certain distance.
If the element has been dragged by more than the set distance on axis X I want to execute a function that will slide the dragged element out of the viewport and slide it back in. I got it to track the distance but now it somehow won't return function as true or false if the condition is not met... I get an error with D undefined. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

I have tried different solutions, but couldn't get neither one of them to work and wasn't able to find an answer on the web.

This what I have done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/DzEu2/4/

```
$(".video").draggable({
    revert: $("#video").mousedown(function (e) {
        $(this).data('p0', {
            x: e.pageX,
            y: e.pageY
        });
    }).mouseup(function (e) {
        p0 = $(this).data('p0'),
        p1 = {
            x: e.pageX,
            y: e.pageY
        },
        d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p0.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p0.y, 2));
    });
    if (d > 100) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

    start: function (event) {
        x = event.originalEvent.pageX;
        y = event.originalEvent.pageY;
        console.log(x, y);
    },
    drag: function (event) {
        if (x && y) {
            axis = Math.abs(event.originalEvent.pageX - x) > Math.abs(event.originalEvent.pageY - y) ? 'x' : 'y';
            $(".video").draggable('option', 'axis', axis);
            x = y = null;
        }
    },
    stop: function () {
        x = y = null;
        $(".video").draggable('option', 'axis', false);
    },
    distance: 20,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are massively overdoing it. Measuring distance travelled on a single axis is rather trivial:

```
revert: function() {
    var orig = $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition.left;
    var curr = $(this).data("uiDraggable").position.left;
    return curr - orig > 100;
}
```

See a working [update on your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzEu2/5/)

Note that the name of the `data` object is different for different versions of jQueryUI. For the one you selected in the fiddle, it's `draggable`, for newer ones it's `uiDraggable`.

---

There are a number of other errors in your code, which I commented out in the fiddle:

- You haven't actually surrounded the code you meant to put in `revert` in a `function(){}`
- Event binders and asynchronous callbacks don't work like what you assume in `mousedown` and `mouseup`. The `d` variable in your `d>100` condition will **always** be `undefined`
- It's generally bad form to use a selector (`".video"`) inside an event handler, when you can get the same object with `this` or `event.currentTarget`.
- Don't end the last property in an object with a comma. Internet explorer randomly decides to hate that.

Summary? Code reviewing is your friend, don't forget about him! :)